# How to use Regex to limit user input to numeric fields, with one allowed decimal and one allowed negative symbol in front

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to only allow numeric values, along with a possible negative symbol at the front of the string, and a single decimal, using Regex in JavaScript. This input value will only allow for a possible 10 digits also.

Currently, when a user inputs text, I have this logic that will only allow numbers, negative signs, and decimals. However, I want to limit the number of the negative sign to one, and only allow this at the front of the string. Also, I want to limit the number of decimals to one.

```
input.slice(0, 10).replace(/[^0-9.\-]/, '');
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: /(-|)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]|)/

Comment: See [this demo](https://tio.run/##TczRCoIwGIbhc69ikrSN/KezgkCiC2kJa/8QY6g4Ew@69yWDoKPv4Pl4X3rR3kzdOMNyCcHZmXT9@J7JlVCQANWKO0QEwPUoTvppzuk@o3WS/F5xxWRHp41lBbulDYfPvVEo4FG0OaGU/7ESCrnCQ5RMbuZdt0mZE1nyrWuG3g/OCje0LLZ5HcIX).

Comment: The question does not include enough context to suggest a solution. While it's certainly possible to create a matching pattern, that might not be the correct solution to the problem. In general, the UI should be providing validation feedback, but not modifying user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
input.slice(0, 10).match(/([-]?)([0-9]+)([.]?)([0-9]?)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short n sweet.

```
/^-?\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,3})?$/
```

- optional negative char. at the start
- allows max of 10 digits next
- again optional decimal group with at most 3 decimal places

These barriers can be modified accordingly.